Visual Studio - missing project Driver: Filessytem MiniFilter
Please explain why I don’t have the “Filter Driver: Filesystem minifilter” template in VIsual Studio 2022:

although it is in the video tutorial I’m watching.

At the same time, I installed the WDK itself from the Microsoft website, but still nothing appeared.
What needs to be done for it to appear? Or in VS2022 - Is this impossible?

For VS 2022, I think you may need to use the higher Windows 11, version 22H2 WDK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#:%7E:text=2019%20System%20Requirements.-,note,-Visual%20Studio%202022
